Keystore Validation Error During Alfresco Deployment on Tomcat
I’m having trouble deploying Alfresco Content Services Community Edition (version 23.2.1) on Tomcat 10.1.28 in windows. After setting up the keystore and configuring alfresco-global.properties, I receive the following error:
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.CORSContextListener] org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 08030002 Keystores are invalid ... Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 08030000 Unable to get secret key: no key information is provided
Configuration Details:

alfresco-global.properties:

Set this property unless you have explicitly chosen to expose some repository APIs without authentication
#solr.secureComms=https
# Custom content and index data location
dir.root=D:/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/alfresco/keystore
dir.keystore=D:/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/alfresco/keystore
dir.contentstore=D:/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/alfresco/contentstore
dir.contentstore.deleted=D:/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/alfresco/contentstore.deleted
# Sample database connection properties
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alfresco?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
db.username=alfresco_user
db.password=***
# URL Generation Parameters (The ${localname} token is replaced by the local server name)
alfresco.context=/alfresco
alfresco.host=localhost
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http
share.context=/share
share.host=localhost
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http
transform.service.enabled=false
local.transform.service.enabled=false
legacy.transform.service.enabled=false
encryption.keystore.path=D:/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/alfresco/keystore/keystore.p12
encryption.keystore.type=pkcs12
encryption.key.alias=metadata
encryption.keystore.password=alfresco
encryption.cipherAlgorithm=AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
encryption.keyAlgorithm=AES
encryption.mac.algorithm=HmacSHA1


Keystore Creation Command:
keytool -genkeypair -alias metadata -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore D:/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/alfresco/keystore/keystore.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass alfresco -keypass alfresco 


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
1.Verified keystore path and permissions.
Recreated the keystore (truststore too) with different parameters.
3.Checked Tomcat logs and configurations.
Question: What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

A warning upfront: never ever regenerate the metadata encryption key if you do not know what you're doing. You may and up in a broken repository.
It looks like you mismatched some parameters for the metadata encryption.
e.g. in alfresco-global.properties you define the locations and types (metadata ecryption keystore.type is expected to be JCEKS):
encryption.keystore.location=${dir.keystore}/keystore
encryption.keystore.provider=
encryption.keystore.type=JCEKS
encryption.keystore.keyMetaData.location=${dir.keystore}/keystore-passwords.properties

In the configured keyMetaData.location file you store the properties for

aliases
keystore.password
metadata.keyData
metadata.algorithm
metadata.password

s. Manage Alfresco keystores
